# Use dependencies in a runtime expression

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've set a variable in a task from another job (task a in job A):

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var1;isOutput=true;]${var1}"
```

And I'd like to use this variable in a job, that's created in a loop, to set a variable for the job in combination with the loop variable:

```
- ${{ each var2 in split(parameters.list, ',') }}:
      - job: get_status
        dependsOn:
          - A
        variables:
          var3: ${{ eq(var2, dependencies.A.outputs['a.var1']) }}
```

This gives an error, as I cannot use dependencies in the runtime expression for var3. How do I access var1 in the expression for var3?

Comment: You can't do that. Expressions in `${{}}` are **compile-time**. They run long before anything created with `##vso[task.setvariable]` runs.